# MYSQL converting query to JSON with my PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Wondering if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong here? Very new to JSONs and arrays etc.

MYSQL query runs fine on phpAdmin and then I am trying to convert to a JSON.

PHP:

```
$dbdata = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$key = $row['Delta'];
if(!isset($dbdata[$key])){
    $dbdata[$key] = array('Delta' => $key);
}
$dbdata[$key][]['Alpha'] = $row['Alpha'];
$dbdata[$key]['Beta'] = $row['Beta'];
$dbdata[$key]['Charlie'] = $row['Charlie'];
$dbdata[$key]['Zulu'] = $row['Zulu'];
}
echo json_encode($dbdata);
```

I cant figure out how to get my JSON looking right to be able to parse to a DataTable. This is what I get:

```
 "dog": {
        "DELTA": "dog",
        "0": {
            "ALPHA": "dry food"
        },
        "BETA": "5",
        "CHARLIE": "6",
        "ZULU": "4216.125",
        "1": {
            "ALPHA": "canned food"
        },
        "2": {
            "ALPHA": "wet food"
        },
        "3": {
            "ALPHA": "wetfood"
        }
```

I believe I need to get to this so that my Datatable will be able to parse and use it. What am I doing wrong?

```
{"dog": {
    [0] "delta" : "dog",
        "Alpha": "value1",
        "Beta": "Value2",
        "Charlie": Value 3,
        "Zulu": Value 4
    },
    [1] "delta" : "cat",
        "Alpha": "value1",
        "Beta": "Value2",
        "Charlie": Value 3,
        "Zulu": Value 4
    }
}}
```

MYSQL Select statement which works perfectly:

```
    (SELECT DELTA, ALPHA, BETA, CHARLIE, ZULU
      FROM table1
      WHERE id = '50' AND spec = 'DELTA1' AND ALPHA > 0
      ORDER BY ALPHA ASC
      LIMIT 10)
      UNION ALL
(SELECT......
```

Repeats 5 times for 5 different DELTA values resulting in 5 columns and 50 rows. I am looking to have DELTA1,DELTA2, DELTA3, DELTA4, DELTA5 as the keys with 10 associative(???) arrays under each DELTA (0-9??)

I can get this....

```
{
    "DELTA": "Delta4",
    "ALPHA": "Value1",
    "BETA": "6",
    "CHARLIE": "5",
    "ZULU": "3906.572"
},
{
    "DELTA": "Delta1",
    "ALPHA": "Value5",
    "BETA": "6",
    "CHARLIE": "5",
    "ZULU": "3906.572"
},
{
    "DELTA": "Delta2",
    "ALPHA": "Value1",
    "BETA": "6",
    "CHARLIE": "5",
    "ZULU": "3906.572"
},
```

But how do I get to this:

```
        "DELTA1": [0]{
                "ALPHA": "Value1",
                "BETA": "6",
                "CHARLIE": "5",
                "ZULU": "3906.572"
            },
                  [1]{
                "ALPHA": "Value1",
                "BETA": "6",
                "CHARLIE": "5",
                "ZULU": "3906.572"
            },
        "DELTA3": [0]{
                "ALPHA": "Value5",
                "BETA": "6",
                "CHARLIE": "5",
                "ZULU": "3906.572"
             },
```

Comment: Please show us your MySQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your desired output structure, I think what you're looking for is this:

```
$dbdata = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $key = $row['DELTA'];
    if(!isset($dbdata[$key])){
        $dbdata[$key] = array();
    }
    $dbdata[$key][]= array('ALPHA' => $row['ALPHA'],
                           'BETA' => $row['BETA'],
                           'CHARLIE' => $row['CHARLIE'],
                           'ZULU' => $row['ZULU']
                           );
}
echo json_encode($dbdata);
```

Note I've uppercased your array indices to reflect what's in the *data* in your question (as opposed to the code), dependent on what is actually in there you may need to capitalise them again.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you build the data for each row separately, and then add the entire thing to the array you are building. That way you can ensure that you won't add keys to weird places in `$dbdata`.

```
$dbdata = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $rowdata = array('Delta' => $row['Delta']);
    $rowdata['Alpha'] = $row['Alpha'];
    $rowdata['Beta'] = $row['Beta'];
    $rowdata['Charlie'] = $row['Charlie'];
    $rowdata['Zulu'] = $row['Zulu'];

    $dbdata[] = $rowdata;
}
echo json_encode($dbdata);
```

If alpha beta charlie etc are the only columns in the result and you're just copying them over, you just need one assignment within the loop:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $dbdata[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Hi Joni, Both of those result in a flat JSON which is where I started but I need to have all 10 Delta sub levels under the Delta1, 2, 3, 4 'headers'

Comment: But that's not what you originally asked. You can edit the question to add more details and clarifications but don't edit it to ask a completely different question.

Comment: sorry Joni - I am not familiar with all the JSON jargon and words to know exactly how to phrase it. All I know is how it is supposed to look (I think)